# Swift 2 CLLocationManager Error updating

Tags: cllocationmanager, swift2, xcode7, xcode7-beta2

i updated Xcode 6 to Xcode 7 beta with Swift 2. I get this error and i can't find out how to fix it, please help me. Thanks. This is my code :

```
 func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]) {
    let location = locations.last as! CLLocation

    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))

    self.map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
}
```

and i get this error :

`Objective-C method 'locationManager:didUpdateLocations:' provided by method 'locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations:)' conflicts with optional requirement method 'locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations:)' in protocol 'CLLocationManagerDelegate'`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Just had the same issue as you, change

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject])
```

to

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
```

Comment: `AnyObject` is a supertype of `CLLocation`. Both should work.

Comment: I know that but when I changed it from [AnyObject] to [CLLocation] the error went away.

Comment: already tried that, it work but then it gave me an error on this line : `let location = locations.last as! CLLocation` said that locations.last can't be a CLLocation

Comment: i fix it by doing `let location = locations.last as! CLLocation!`

Comment: I like how, in the Stanford iOS courses, Paul Hegarty was complaining about the "AnyObject" supertype and now Apple fixed it in Swift 2. :P

Answer (score 2):

Click on your project - go to Build Phases->Link Binary With Libraries and add CoreLocation.framework

```
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var LatitudeGPS = NSString()
var LongitudeGPS = NSString()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    updateLocation()

func updateLocation() {
    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    //self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 10
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]) {

    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation() // Stop Location Manager - keep here to run just once

    LatitudeGPS = String(format: "%.6f", manager.location!.coordinate.latitude)
    LongitudeGPS = String(format: "%.6f", manager.location!.coordinate.longitude)
    print("Latitude - \(LatitudeGPS)")

}
```

This is my code which works on xcode 7, also I did have to clean my code (Product->Clean)

Answer (score 1):

You need to mark your class or method with `@objc` attribute. So either:

```
@objc class MyManagerDelegate: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]) {
        ...
    }

}
```

Or:

```
class MyManagerDelegate: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @objc func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]) {
        ...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by following code:

```
//CLLocationManagerDelegate
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]) {
    let location:CLLocation = locations[locations.count-1] as! CLLocation 

    if (location.horizontalAccuracy > 0) {
        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        print(location.coordinate, terminator: "")
        updateWeatherInfo(location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let location = locations.last as! CLLocation!
    manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.001, longitudeDelta: 0.001))
    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
}
```